# react-native upgrade will change the path of MainActivity.java, how to stay with the original path?

Tags: react-native

I have cloned the [f8app](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app) project

then run `react-native upgrade` in this project

It will create MainActivity.java at path`android/app/src/main/java/com/f8v2/MainActivity.java` instead of use the original path.

the original path is

`android/app/src/main/java/com/facebook/f8/MainActivity.java`

below is my operation

```
$ git clone git@github.com:fbsamples/f8app.git
$ cd f8app
$ npm install
$ ls android/app/src/main/java/com/facebook/f8
MainActivity.java
$ react-native upgrade
Upgrading project to react-native v0.28.0
...
   create android/app/src/main/java/com/f8v2/MainActivity.java
```

#### Additional Information

- React Native version: 0.28.0+
- Platform: android
- Operating System: MacOS, Windows

actually it's not a problem of version.

It will create new files in other versions too, .e.g. [0.32.0](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/GitHubPopular/issues/15)

Looks like that it will create new files just based on the name in package.json instead of existing package name in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, I have checked the code in upgrade process here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.38-stable/local-cli/generator-android/index.js

```
this.option('package', {
  desc: 'Package name for the application (com.example.app)',
  type: String,
  defaults: 'com.' + this.name.toLowerCase()
});

...

var javaPath = path.join.apply(
  null,
  ['android', 'app', 'src', 'main', 'java'].concat(this.options.package.split('.'))
);
this.fs.copyTpl(
  this.templatePath(path.join('package', '**')),
  this.destinationPath(javaPath),
  templateParams
);
```

how to stay with the original path?